# Custom WIM shows up blank in Windows Setup

Tags: windows-10, dism, wim

I am trying to set up a custom image to load with windows setup.  It works fine, but for some reason the operating system has a blank selection in Windows Setup.[image: Windows Setup]

But when I check the WIM title and description it's all properly filled out.  What am I doing wrong?
[image: WIM Description]

Answer (score 0):

Download Win Toolkit
https://www.chip.de/downloads/Win-Toolkit_66546474.html

[image]

Run Win Toolkit

```
Intermediate -> WIM Manager -> Browse -> Browse for WIM -> 
Select Image Name -> Edit -> Edit Name, Edit Desc, Edit Display Name, Edit Display Description and Edit Flag
```

[image]